# Evaluating an array within array in VueJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, vue.js

I am using VueJs and will be using logic to bring a user to one of three components based on the outcome of an if statement.  The property being brought into this child component from its parent is userResultData. The idea is that the data in this it passes the properties of the userResultData array and move into more components once I can get the console to show things are processing the way they should.  Inside userResultData, it has two more arrays, employees or managers.  The user can have values in employees or in managers or both.  If it there are only values in the employees array, one action will result.  The same applies for managers.  If both have a value then it's the final condition since it has both.

However, I am getting an interesting error, so clearly something isn't right.  Pretty sure it has to do with how I am passing the args.  I'm relatively new to JavaScript and this framework, so if anyone wouldn't mind a simple explanation on what I can fix, it's much appreciated.  userResultArrayData is the arg I need to pass in here, right? If so, how would I then pass it through?

Here is what I have:

```
import EmployeeAndManagerUser from '../Organization/EmployeeAndManagerComponent.vue';
import EmployeeUser from '../Organization/EmployeeComponent.vue';
import ManagerUser from '../Organization/ManagerComponent.vue';

export default {
    props: ['userResultData'],
    components: {
        ManagerUser,
        EmployeeUser,
        EmployeeAndManagerUser
    },
    data() {
        return {
            userResultArrayData: null,
            managerUser: null,
            employeeUser: null,
            employeeAndManagerUser: null
        }
    },
    methods: {
        evaluateTypeOfUser(){
            if (Object.keys(this.managers).length === 0 && Object.keys(this.employees).length !== 0) {
                console.log('result matched with employee ');
            }
            else if (Object.keys(this.managers).length !== 0 && Object.keys(this.employees).length === 0) {
                console.log('result matched with manager ');
            }
            else {
                console.log('result is both employee and manager');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error: 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.keys ()
    at VueComponent.evaluateTypeOfUser (app.js:38281)

Comment: Well, they return data that is coming in from the parent component over this one.  There are values in there that can be seen in the Vue tool for Chrome. It goes Search -> this component ->whatever type of user's component

Comment: They return the array, but properties such as managers and employees doesn't exist into the Vue object, and when you write `this.magagers` vue goes to data model and lookup for them - since they are not here it would return undefined.Could you post your data structure of `userResultData` ?

Comment: Did you debug your code?

Comment: @BelminBedak

userResultData[
id: ''
employees: []
managers: []
first_name: ''
last_name: '',
city: '',
phone: ''
email
]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The child component doesn't know about `managers` and `employees`, it only knows `userResultData`. You need to explicitly set the `managers` and `employees` properties in your `data` function.

```
data() {
    return {
        userResultArrayData: null,
        managerUser: null,
        employeeUser: null,
        employeeAndManagerUser: null,
        employees: this.userResultData.employees,
        managers: this.userResultData.managers,
    }
},
```

Or just reference the properties properly

```
Object.keys(this.userResultData.managers)
```

Comment: Ah, thought it had to be something simple.  This makes sense. Thank you!